# Determine whether the Text Frame, text within the Text Frame or no Text Frame or text portion is selected

Tags: adobe-illustrator, javascript

**Some Background**

We work with product label design in Adobe Illustrator CC 2022. The purpose of this script is to convert our metric value to Imperial value depending on the user selection: ML to FL OZ or G to OZ. The math/conversion part works fine.

**What I need guidance with**

*I need to determine whether the user has:*

1. Selected the Text Frame itself.
2. Whether the user has their cursor active inside the Text Frame or has selected a portion of text.
3. Whether none of the two above is the case.

The included code snippet does work for numbers 1 & 2 above but number 3 on the list I can't seem to get right. It seems to totally ignore the nested "Catch". I am not very familiar with Try/Catch blocks and have tried if/then statements with no luck.

Is there any way to get the script to **not** ignore the nested catch alternatively, is there another workaround perhaps?

The code snippet in question (I have included comments for ease of reference):

```
if (app.documents.length > 0)
{
    var $docRef = app.activeDocument;
    var $rslt = "I am the replacement value";
    try
    {
        //check if the selected object is a "Text Frame"
        
        if($docRef.selection[0].typename == "TextFrame")
        {
            $docRef.selection[0].contents = $rslt;
        }
    }
    catch(e1)
    {
        alert("e1 :"+e1.message); // "e1: undefined is not an object"
        
        //DO THE FOLLOWING: Ignore the error and try the nested check
        
        try
        {
            //check if the parent object of selected is a "Story"... thus editable text within a Text Frame
            
            if($docRef.selection.parent.typename == "Story")
            {
                $docRef.selection.contents = $rslt;
            }
        }
        catch(e2)
        {
            alert("e2 :"+e2.message);  // "e2: undefined is not an object"
            
            //DO THE FOLLOWING: Assume that no ediatble text is selected, create a Text Frame and populate it with $rslt value

            alert("Creating new Text Frame");
            
            //MY PROBLEM: It ignores this Catch step completely...
        }
    }
}
```